# Wrong time in log4j logs on Windows Server 2003

Tags: java, time, log4j, windows-server-2003

I have a "strange" problem. I use log4j in a Java application.
On my PC the times that appear in log4j generated logs are fine, corresponding to the local time of my machine.

The problem is that when I deploy the application on a Windows Server 2003, the times that appear in the log files are going haywire. The date is fine, but the hours and minutes not at all. They don't match at all the server's local time. And I doesn't seem to be a time zone issue since the difference between the local time and log time seems to be 4h 30 minutes. I know, there are some timezones with 30 minutes, but, still...

Does anybody know how is this possible?

Here you have the conversion pattern for appender R:

```
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

I put only this part of the log4j.properties because only this one is interesting for my problem.

Comment: What are the timezone system settings for your local machine and the server?

Comment: Mine is (UTC + 1:00) and the server's is UTC

Comment: Are they at least sequential and growing as the server runs longer?   You mention not correlating but I think you mean they don't match the server's clock.

Comment: Yes, you are correct - I meant that they don't match the server's clock. I edited my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Still, it looks like a time zone problem. Don't you, for example, run the application on a different user account than you use for checking the date on the server?

Log4j takes the default time zone, so you could try running your application with the additional command line option:

```
-Duser.timezone=UTC
```

and see if it anything changes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but no, the application is run from the administrator account (the same used for checking the date on the server).

Comment: @ovdsrn What happens if you run it with the -Duser.timezone then?